# How to set InputGestureText automatically on all menus?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, menu

In WinForms, I could specify a key combination for a command, and it would be displayed automatically in the menu item. In fact, this was also true in Delphi, more than ten years ago.

In WPF, however, I bind the input gestures in one place, and then have to remember to set the `InputGestureText` every time I use an input gesture, manually.

How can I have all InputGestureTexts on all menus in my application be set automatically based on the current key binding?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is no automation built in but that should not stop you from making one yourself, should not be too hard. You could iterate over your menu-tree and add the `InputGestureText` based on the `InputBindings` or do it the other way around (preferably with a view-model-hierarchy backing the menu).